# Java MongoDB Driver in Groovy misses records on find() that turn up on find({field: known_value})

Tags: mongodb, groovy, iterator, set

You can see examples of what I mean here:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel
import com.mongodb.*
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat
import org.bson.Document

// Get stuff from MongoDB
mongoClient = new MongoClient()
database = mongoClient.getDatabase("relato")

// Create nodes from companies
companies = database.getCollection("companies")
companies_cursor = companies.find().iterator()

try {
  while (companies_cursor.hasNext()) {
    record = companies_cursor.next()
    domain = record.domain
    if(domain == 'ibm.com') {
      // I neve print...
      print("IBM found!\n")
    }
  }
} finally {
  companies_cursor.close()
}

// However... this finds a record!
companies_cursor = companies.find(new Document('domain', 'ibm.com'))
// ==>Document{{_id=54dd19c08899a4c549dc71d6, update_time=Fri Apr 10 14:36:18 PDT 2015, domain=ibm.com, name=IBM}}
```

I can't figure out why a general find() misses documents I know are there from the mongo prompt, but find({field: known_value}) turns these records up.

How do I actually list all records in a table, if find().iterator() isn't doing it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of the driver?

Comment: I tried your code with the 3.1.0 and 3.0.4 mongo-java-driver and the domain match in the `while` loop works fine in both cases if I insert a document like your example. How many other documents are in your companies collection? If you print all documents in the loop is the document with "ibm.com" the only one missing?